# Macbook Pro 2015 with El Capitan went black screen after login

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have macbook pro 2015 model with El Capitan.
Today when i clicked on reminder notification after login it fluctuated and finally went to black screen.

So I tried following steps till now:-
1. Restarted the macbook
2. Tried SMC reset 
3. Tried PRAM reset but no benefit.

Also on forced shutdown(by pressing and holding power button) and restarting the macbook apple logo is not coming at start now only sound of starting is coming.
Now login screen is also not coming just black screen in whole process.

Please give suggestions.

Comment: Try starting in single user mode by holden cmd+s after the startup sound. If you can login successfully, post the log entries in the console. also, try creating another user for testing purpose and try logging into the test user account to see if the black screen appears there too.

Comment: Also check the screen against a bright light source - see if the screen works but the backlight has failed.

Comment: It has stopped powering on and even charging so i guess now i ll have to head to Apple Service Center as it is in warranty yet.

Comment: It was an issue of motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the answer after getting issue resolved.

It was a technical hardware failure of motherboard in my case.
So the whole motherboard set was replaced.

P.S. - But before going directly to hardware failure please go through the steps shared in question and the comments above by @J.C. and @Tetsujin